# Using values from a JS script to design bars in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bar-chart

I have designed a grid and labels for the canvas, and my last task is to use information from an array in a JS file called taxForms.js to create the bars within the canvas layout. I want to solve it with a for loop, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Html and Canvas code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tax forms: Bar chart with lines</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="taxForms.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      #chart {
        margin: 1rem auto;
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <canvas id="chart" width="700" height="550"></canvas>

    <script>
      const canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      /* Draw a line from (fromX, fromY) to (toX, toY) */
      function drawLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) {
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(toX, toY);
        context.lineTo(fromX, fromY);
        context.stroke();
      }

      /* Draw a text (string) on (x, y) */
      function drawText(text, x, y) {
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.fillText(text, x, y);
      }

      /* Draw a text and with a line to its right */
      function drawLineWithText(text, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) {
        drawText(text, fromX - 50, fromY + 5);
        drawLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
      }

      /* Insert your code here. */
      for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--){
        drawLineWithText(i*100000,50,550-i*50,600,550-i*50);
      }

      /*Code for the small labels*/
      context.beginPath();
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.rect(600,50,50,20);
      context.fill();
      drawText('Income',655,64);

      context.beginPath();
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.rect(600,75,50,20);
      context.fill();
      drawText('Wealth',655,89);

      /*Code for the bars*/
      /*relevant code for the bars starts under here*/
      function rect(fX, fY, tX, tY) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fill();
      }
      for (var i = 1; i < taxForms.lenght; i++){
        rect(10, 10, 10, i*2);
      }
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
const taxForms = [
  {
    realName: "Bruce Wayne",
    income: 750000,
    wealth: 300000
  },
  {
    realName: "John Blake",
    income: 440000,
    wealth: 832000
  },
  {
    realName: "Selina Kyle",
    income: 640000,
    wealth: 432000
  }
];
```

An image of how it looks now, vs how it should look
[image: How it looks now]

[image: How it should look]

Comment: can you add your code to Codpan or Fiddle or other online editors?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hbLtu51e/#&togetherjs=rSq52Sv0AD
will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rect` function never calls `context.rect`

```
function rect(fX, fY, tX, tY) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.rect(fX, fY, tX, tY)
  context.fill();
}
```

It's `length` not `lenght`

```
for (let i = 1; i < taxForms.length; i++){
  rect(10, 10, 10, i*2);
}
```